# Unit Test method with EF.Functions.Contains()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-core-2.2

I have got a method which contains a call to `EF.Functions.Contains`. Now I want to write unit tests for this method with a InMemory database, but I am getting instantly the following exception `System.InvalidOperationException : The 'Contains' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation.`

My method looks like this

```
var attributeValues = Context.AssetAttributeValues
                                         .Include(a => a.AssetAttribute)
                                         .Include(a => a.Asset)
                                         .Where(i => EF.Functions.Contains(i.Value, searchString));
```

I know that this exception is thrown because I have got no fulltext index on my InMemory database compared to my productive SQL Server instance but how do I get the same index on the InMemory database?

Is there any way to get arround this exception?

Comment: One solution is use: `.Where(i => i.Value.Contains(searchString));`

Comment: @TanvirArjel this is unfortunately no option, because this is a huge table so that I had to create a fulltext index. With your solution the sql would just make a `LIKE '%searchstring%'` operation which is definitly not fast...

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, `EF.Functions.Contains` can not be used in an InMemory database.

A workaround is to use [`IsSqlServer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdatabasefacadeextensions.issqlserver) to check whether you are running against a SQL Server  or InMemory provider.

```
if(Context.IsSqlServer())  
    return Context.AssetAttributeValues
                                         .Include(a => a.AssetAttribute)
                                         .Include(a => a.Asset)
                                         .Where(i => EF.Functions.Contains(i.Value, searchString));
else
    return Context.AssetAttributeValues
                                         .Include(a => a.AssetAttribute)
                                         .Include(a => a.Asset)
                                         .Where(i => i.Value.Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to write code so that that code can pass a unit test. Because what is that test proving then?

Comment: @CodeCaster: I agree, this is not a solution, just a workaround to the problem posed in the question. In fact, by doing this you are shipping an untested if-block to production.